# Showing scroll indicator all the time UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I would like to show my scrollview all the time. I have looked around for some answers and i found this which i implemented:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(flashIndicator), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and the function:

```
func flashIndicator(){

    informationView.flashScrollIndicators()
}
```

To make sure it is getting called i put a simple print in the function and its getting called many times...

But the scroll is not being shown? Just when im actually scrolling. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Curious... Try slowing it down to see if it is just flashing so fast that it does not appear visible. Since the default state is not shown it could possibly be showing and then reverting before someone can even see it.

Comment: @Ike10 you were correct. I changed it and it flashed. The problem still is now that it does not show " all the time" cant have the scroll flickering all the time. There is no way to fix this you think?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Apple frowns upon scroll indicators been constantly shown. Thus, I believe that have deliberately made it a private API. So in short, it may be possible, but I don't think the app would be allowed into the app store.